# Inserting new item to json object of nested arrays within JSONB_SET

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I have a table (log_table) and in this table, there is a nested array json field (activities). With using this activities field, I want to insert new field to nested array.

log_table:

```
- id:long
- activities:json
- date:timestamp
```

example activities field:

```
[ 
   { 
      "actionType":"NOTIFICATION",
      "items":null
   },
   { 
      "actionType":"MUTATION",
      "items":[ 
         { 
            "id":387015007,
            "name":"epic",
            "value":{ 
               "currency":"USD",
               "amount":1.76
            }
         },
         { 
            "id":386521039,
            "name":"test",
            "value":{ 
               "currency":"USD",
               "amount":1.76
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

As query, I've tried:

```
update 
table_log m 
set activities = 
jsonb_set(
   m.activities::jsonb, 
   array['activities',(pos1-1)::text,'items',(pos-1)::text,'newId'],
   ((obj->>'id'))::jsonb 
)::json
from table_log l
cross join jsonb_array_elements(l.activities::jsonb) with ordinality arr1(elems, pos1)
cross join jsonb_array_elements(case elems->'items' when 'null' then '[null]' else elems->'items' end)  with ordinality arr(obj, pos)
where (obj->>'id')::int = 387015007 and l.id = m.id;
```

With this query, I got an error like below:

```
ERROR:  path element at position 1 is not an integer: "activities"
```

Expected Output:

```
[ 
   { 
      "actionType":"NOTIFICATION",
      "items":null
   },
   { 
      "actionType":"MUTATION",
      "items":[ 
         { 
            "id":387015007,
            "newId":387015007,
            "name":"epic",
            "value":{ 
               "currency":"USD",
               "amount":1.76
            }
         },
         { 
            "id":386521039,
            "name":"test",
            "value":{ 
               "currency":"USD",
               "amount":1.76
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it like below:

```
update 
table_log m 
set activities = 
jsonb_set(
   m.activities::jsonb, 
   array[(pos1-1)::text,'items',(pos-1)::text,'newId'],
   ((obj->>'id'))::jsonb 
)::json
from table_log l
cross join jsonb_array_elements(l.activities::jsonb) with ordinality arr1(elems, pos1)
cross join jsonb_array_elements(case elems->'items' when 'null' then '[null]' else elems->'items' end)  with ordinality arr(obj, pos)
where (obj->>'id')::int = 387015007 and l.id = m.id;
```

So the problem was;

`array['activities',...]` -> 'activities' is redundant in here.